How to render a link to a page fragment in Twig
I have a Twig template that prints a link with the following code:
{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}

This code is rendered as an a element with a href attribute similar with the following:
https://www.mysite.com/alias/to/page

I would like the href attribute to link to a specific element in the destination page, that is to create an a element that contains a href attribute with a contents similar with the following:
https://www.mysite.com/alias/to/page#secondary_title

Thank you.

In the end I cam up with the following code:
{{ item.title }}
but something is telling me that this is not the correct solution. I would like to modify item.url to contain the # part.

Templates should display data, not manipulate data, so the clean way would be simply editing the source of item.url in the admin UI. There is no built-in method to manipulate a Drupal URL object in Twig.
However, if editing the source is not possible for whatever reason, then your solution actually is not that bad at all, because |render is one of the few options that will work with internal AND external AND unrouted links.

It's fine not to allow the modification of PHP objects inside Twig templates. At first I thought that this would be the best solution because I've seen that the link function is able to assemble a link fragment from the information it receives as parameters (title, url, attributes, etc). Which is excelent. In fact I was expecting to find some function tha allows me to set the "#" part. But there is no such a function. Why not? Is there any justification?
